# Semantic UI forcing form fields two 2 columns on phone display

Tags: semantic-ui

I trying to set up a form with two narrow selects in a row and want the selects to stay in two columns. No matter what I try they selects always stack on a mobile size display. How can I force them to not stack and stay in two columns?

```
<div class="two fields">
  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui sub header">County</div>
    <select class="ui  dropdown" v-model="district" v-on="change: selectCity" >
        <option></option>
        <option v-repeat="districts" value="{{district}}">{{district}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <div class="ui sub header">City <span class="ms">(select county first)</span></div>
    <select class="ui  dropdown" v-model="map_area" v-on="change: clearFoundCt">
        <option></option>
        <option v-repeat="cities" value="{{map_area}}">{{map_area |   trimcity}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Im not sure if you have figured this out yet or not, but try putting them inside the grid class and use doubling.

Here is a snippet from the document page [here](http://1.semantic-ui.com/collections/grid.html)

```
<div class="ui grid">
    <div class="doubling two column row">
        <div class="column">foo</div>
        <div class="column">bar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If that doesn't work try this

```
<div class="ui two column grid">
   <div class="column">foo</div>
   <div class="column">bar</div> 
</div>
```

The documentation contains a responsive pattern guide on how to determine the number of grids you will end up with for mobile interface.

I hope this helped.

**UPDATE:**

So I just tried this and it worked

```
<div class="ui two column grid form">
    <div class="column two field">
       <input type="text" name="first-name" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="column two  field">
       <input type="text" name="last-name" placeholder="Last Name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Not sure if that was what you were looking for.

Oh and also I couldn't get the first example to work properly with `doubling two column`, but if you use `<div class="doubling four column row">` you will basically get something that looks like this

for tablet/monitors

```
 ______ ______ ____________
|      |      |            |
|  foo | bar  |            |
____________________________
```

and this for mobile

```
 _____________ _____________
|             |             |
|     foo     |     bar     |
____________________________
```

So as you can see it works, but the display isn't elegant on monitors and tablets.